# Return integer 0

Tags: php

Sorry for bad english , used Google.translate

There is a code that returns a value to a int, if set . Otherwise it returns false

```
if (isset($this->variable))
   return intval ($this->variable);
else
   return false;
```

On the receiving side condition

```
if ($return_value) {
   // Here code
}
```

The problem is that if the returned value is 0, this is false, and the code is executed . But as the value of 0 is also important to me . If returned as a string , it is still treated as false.

`define ('false', 'value')` does not work.

Introduced his constant for this , but you have to rewrite a bunch of code for additional testing

```
(if($return_value! == my_false_constant)
```

That is not quite satisfied.

What options are there to solve this problem ?

Comment: [Check the comaprison tables](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php), and check the operators: `===` and `!==` are strict (type & value) comaprison operators

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if ($return_value !== false) {

}
```

Using !== (or ===) instead of just != or == also tests the type of the value.

Answer (score 1):

Use strict comparison with ===.
See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

```
if(1 === true) //returns FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
(if($return_value !== false){
// do work
}
```

Comparisons:

- == means same value
- === means same value AND same type
- ! == means not (same value)
- !== means not (same value and same type)

SO:

- 0 == false //is true
- 0 === false //is false

Answer (score 0):

Simply `! ==` does not equal `!==`, as is not valid PHP code